# Need more insight on a formula

Tags: linear-algebra, modules, contest-math

Following is a part of a programming contest problem.

Given $C_{1},m,n,o,x,y,z,c,d,K,J$ are positive integers

$ C_{i} = \left\{ 
  \begin{array}{l l}
    (m*C_{i-1}^2 + n*C_{i-1} + o) \bmod J & \quad \text{if $c^i \bmod d <= K$}\\
    (x*C_{i-1}^2 + y*C_{i-1} + z) \bmod J & \quad \text{if $c^i \bmod d > K$}
  \end{array} \right.$

I noticed that the value of $C_{2}$ to $C_{x}$ repeats. i.e

$C_{x+1} = C_{2}, C_{x+2} = C_{3} .....C_{2x-1}=C_{x}, C_{2x} = C_{2} ......$

Is my observation correct? and is there is any other characteristics I should know of.

Comment: Yes, the sequence $C_i = f(C_{i-1})$ repeats eventually, and if  you are interesred in programming an algorithm this may help: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection

Comment: @gammatester is it guaranteed that $C_{2}$ to $C_{x}$ is unique?

Comment: IMO yes, with your definitions and if $x$ is minimal (i.e. the 'smallest period'), because $C_i$ is uniquely determined by $C_{i-1}$ and some constants.

Comment: I just realized that $C_i = f(C_{i-1}, c^i \pmod d, \dots)!\;$ So the situation is
slightly more complicated. The result that the sequence is periodic is still valid, but the uniqueness applies to the **pairs** $(C_i, c_i)$ where $c_i =c^i \pmod d,\;$ i.e. the $C_i$ alone are not necessarily unique.